# How to get a certain (determined by var) value in a string of several space-separated values

Tags: autohotkey

The string looks something like this:

3.142 43.674 3.453 1.233 543.234

I got a var which in this case can vary from 1 to 5, which I want to determine which one of the values to extract into a new var. So if my var is 4, I want the fourth value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out the different loop commands from the help file? In this case, you would want to parse your string with a space delimiter. Here is the help file information: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopParse.htm.

```
sVar := "3.142 43.674 3.453 1.233 543.234"
Inputbox , sInput , Which Value? , Which value do you want?
If !ErrorLevel
    Loop , Parse , sVar , %A_Space%
        If (A_Index = sInput)
            MsgBox , %A_LoopField%
```

Comment: Thank you very much Evan. This seems to be the way to go. I have read about loop parse before but never used it, and now I was more into some RegEx-thing with sInput-var in the needle. Loop parse seems to make more sense. But it has to be a "{" and a "}" under the loop, right?

Comment: No problem, glad to help. The braces are only necessary if you need to execute more than one line of code; otherwise, only the line following it will be executed.

Comment: Yes, and I guess it's only one line cause the MsgBox is "hidden" under the If...? While your solution works flawlessly I've encountered an unexpected problem, since digit group separation makes some values (>= 1000) look like 1 020.00 while I need it to be 1020.00. But that's a new question posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52376511/parse-numerical-values-with-space-as-delimiter-while-ignoring-digit-grouping-i

Comment: Correct. I should have clarified it to say, "more than one line of [un-nested] code".